# Integrating modelId from Azure Digital Twin into Time Series Insights

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights, azure-digital-twins

What I'm currently trying to get my head around is the ability to integrate the `modelId` from an Azure Digital Twin instance within Time Series Insights. I understand that Time Series Insights (Gen2) accepts the datatype of a string, however when I try to initiate that state, it doesn't appear within TSI when a connection is successfully established between Azure Digital Twin and Time Series Insights.

Streaming logs showing the **modelId** being recognised but not parsed into **TSI**:
[image]

Is there potentially a way to define this `modelId` so that it can be viewed as an **instance** or even as a **hierarchy** within Time Series Insights, so that I don't manually have to this step?

Many thanks,

Matas

Comment: Same question in Microsoft Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178477/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Device id / some meaningful attributes from event source to be mapped as **timeseriesid**. TSI will automatically map with the event source once we set the attribute. We can set multiple attributes. **This should be done during the creation of TSI**. Once created, you cannot change the timeseriesid.

Add **modelId** as **timeseriesid**. It should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to insert modelID as one of the instance field of an instance in TSI through its ingestion service.
If that is the case, unfortunately we cant insert instance fields through ingestor service. Instead you can call the API to insert instance field and its values. The API could be called from your Translator function or using upload JSON option in TSI model page.
TSI has its own syntax please refer to the attachment for details

Screenshot showing syntax for inserting instance field with its value:
[image]

Please refer to the following documentation for information about TSI model, Patch Syntax and API details!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-model-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/timeseriesinstances/executebatch#instancesbatchput

Please let me know if I could be of further help!